# Variable not being shared as expected between shell commands between Jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following stage declarative code:
stage('Initialization') {

```
        steps {
            script {
                TAG_VALUE=sh(script:"cd srcCode;git name-rev --name-only HEAD",returnStdout: true)
            }
            sh '''
                echo "build:${MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION}:${TAG_VALUE}-${BUILD_VERSION}"
            '''
            echo "build1:${MAJOR_MINOR_VERSION}:${TAG_VALUE}-${BUILD_VERSION}"
            buildName "${TAG_VALUE} - ${BUILD_VERSION}"
        }
    }
```

However the code that runs inside the sh command doesn't seem to pickup the TAG_VALUE variable set previously in the Script block but the subsequent code outside of it does.

See output in bold below:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo build:1.0:-96
**build:1.0:-96**
[Pipeline] echo
build1:1.0:remotes/origin/master
-96
[Pipeline] step
New run name is 'remotes/origin/master
 - 96'
```

According to previous posts this should work:
https://serverfault.com/questions/884764/jenkins-pipeline-file-passing-jenkinsfile-variables-into-further-commands/884798

Comment: If it wouldn't pick up the TAG_VALUE variable it would crash with an error. Could the variable be an empty string? Could you print just TAG_VALUE

Comment: @smelm I think it's empty as you said.